# we are getting data error while loading from Oracle to Snowflake

Tags: oracle, dataframe, file, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my data Address column having this information(Tamilnadu, HNo: 90, India,Ramasamy). While loading data from Oracle to Snowflake we are getting below error.

> Unable to copy files into table.
>
> Numeric value '1,"Tamilnadu, HNo: 90, India,Ramasamy"' is not
> recognized File '@SAMPLE_TEST/ui1675860748054/test1.csv', line 1,
> character 1 Row 1, column "SAMPLE_TEST"["ID":1] If you would like to
> continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such
> as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more
> information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a
> SQL client

NOTE: We have two columns in our table (ID, Address)

kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Thank you.

Data should be copy to snowflake as below format "Tamilnadu, HNo: 90, India,Ramasamy".

```
Loading as --- "Tamilnadu
expected as --- "Tamilnadu, HNo: 90, India,Ramasamy"
```

Comment: From the error message, you are attempting to load that string into a numeric column. Please explain your load process in more detail - I assume you are loading from a file (e.g. AWS S3 or Azure Blob storage) using Snowflake's COPY INTO command? If you are, please update your question with your COPY command, the file format you are using and some sample rows of data

Comment: Thank you Nick,  Here is the file format objective.   create or replace file format TEST_FILE_FORMAT
   type = 'CSV'
   field_delimiter = 'None'
   ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'None'
   error_on_column_count_mismatch= false
   EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE
   skip_header=0;                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                        
 i am loading from local drive.

Comment: If you have no field delimited how do you expect Snowflake to separate the data between col1/col2? Based on the error it looks to me you should set **FIELD_DELIMITER=','** and **FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'**